# Image attributes get set to zero when inserting values with "px" into jquery's attr method

Tags: jquery, attributes, attr

I found that the jquery attr() method doesn't like accepting values with "px" in them.  The resulting images end up with zero width and height!  Is this a bug, an oversight or some feature?

It is easy to get around, but I really don't like setting values without units.  It could lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Tested the following in firefox 3.6 and opera 11:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="return.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="links" style="width:500px; background:#000;">
  <img src="images/ref.png" width="500px" height="500px" alt="reference" />
</div>

</body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('div#links').css({ 'height':"300px" });
$('div#links img').attr({ 'width':"100px", 'height':"100px" }); // This doesn't work!
//$('div#links img').attr({ 'width':"100", 'height':"100" }); // This works.

});
```

Answer (score 5):

When you use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr), you are setting an attribute.  You use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) for setting a `style` property.

You wouldn't use `px` in a `width` attribute in HTML, so you don't use it in `attr` either.

Comment: But htmldog recommends setting the width and height attributes for <img> elements.  I thought it was the one exception to the _html for structure, css for presentation_ rule.  Is this practice frowned upon now?

Comment: @shafty Not to my knowledge. Just set the dimensions without `px`. It's the correct way to do it.

Comment: Putting width and height attributes on <img> tags makes them render fast as the browser knows exactly where the image is going and how to scale it. But like the answer says, you just don't put the 'px' on the attributes, but you do in the CSS.